# Encrypt file using GPG with exec()

Tags: php, gnupg

I'm trying to encrypt a file using GPG through exec(). The file I want to encrypt is created before running this command.

```
$fesha = date("mdY");
$file_name = "FILE_$fesha.txt";
$myfile = fopen($file_name, "w");
//MySQL query
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);

$password = "*password*";
$commando = "gpg --encrypt --passphrase=\"$password\" --armor --batch --yes --trust-model always -r **email@public.key** \"$file_name\"";
echo  shell_exec($commando);
echo $commando;
```

I run the PHP script while watching the "output" folder, the text file is created without any issues,
but the asc file is never created.

If I manually run the output from the PHP file (the actual GPG command) the encrypted file is created without any issue or error message.

I've been trying to solve this for a couple of hours.

I tried to use the class approach (***$gpg = new gnupg();***)  but I was unable to install all the PECL modules/extensions.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using `pass_thru()`? -- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php

Comment: Just tried, still unable to make it work... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours and hours of research, trial and error with more command parameters, trying with permissions on the server-side, tried to add www-data user to the admin realm, modifying permissions on /home/www-data/.gnupg and /home/mainuser/.gnupg folders...

I did something "dumb" and send this command (***$commando = "gpg --gen-key";***) to see if I can generate a secret key through the PHP script because I kinda figure out it had to do with permissions at this point and I was not able to log in as www-data into the terminal.

Obviously I got no interactive response, but I guess It just created an empty key or something because after I tried the original command again:

***$commando = "gpg --encrypt --passphrase=\"$password\" --armor --batch --yes --trust-model always -r email@public.key \"$file_name\"";***

It actually worked!
The server created the text file and the encrypted file.

So, I do not want to believe that silly thing ("***gpg --gen-key***") actually "solved the mystery", I want to believe it was a combination of all I did.

Just in case someone else has this issue, I found these articles really helpful.

[Using GPG (GnuPG with PHP on Server](https://maslosoft.com/blog/2017/09/12/using-gpg-with-php-on-server/).

[gpg: WARNING: unsafe ownership on homedir /home/user/.gnupg](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/452020/gpg-warning-unsafe-ownership-on-homedir-home-user-gnupg)

[What are the correct permissions for the .gnupg enclosing folder?](https://superuser.com/questions/954509/what-are-the-correct-permissions-for-the-gnupg-enclosing-folder-gpg-warning)

Answer (score 0):

I updated /etc/passwd and changed the home directory for www-data. Next I copied with recursion the /root/.gnupg to the home directory of www-data and change the owner to www-data. Seemed to work. GPG provides like a 80% smaller file size. Use 2>&1 to expose output after line return.